# OO JavaScript Method calling Issue

Tags: javascript, methods

Gurus, I am new to JS. I am getting an error, "Unable to find method createEntitlementTree". Can you please help how I should be writing and invoking this method? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Ext.define('Myviews.UserGroupManagerPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
.......
    createUserGroupForm: function(){
        this.gridPanel = Ext.create( 'Ext.FormPanel', {
            region: 'center',
            collapsible: false,
            floatable: false,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'userGroupName',
                    fieldLabel: 'User Group Name',
                    width: 210
                },
                createEntitlementTree()
            ]
        });
        return this.gridPanel;
    },
    createEntitlementTree: function() {
        return Ext.create( 'Ext.tree.Panel', {
            border: true,
            rootVisible: false,
            useArrows: true,
            frame: true,
            title: 'Entitlements',
            width: 300,
            height: 350,
            initComponent: function() {
                this.store = Ext.create( 'Ext.data.TreeStore', {
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        url: '/TradeHubSVN/admin/getAllEntitlements.json'
                    }
                });
                this.callParent( arguments);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Extraneous code should be removed from [samples](http://sscce.org/), with an eye towards making them complete, concise & representative.

Comment: SO uses a Q&A site, rather than a forum. Comments aren't meant for general messaging. If an answer is helpful, up-vote it. If it resolves your issue, [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) it. Consider picking a [meaningful username](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). One advantage to this is others can use [at-replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) and you'll get a notification that someone has addressed you in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

`createEntitlementTree()` has to be called in the context of an object of the right type.  You can't just call it all by itself like you are trying to do.

I don't really understand how `createUserGroupForm()` is invoked, but you may need `this.createEntitlementTree()` or `obj.createEntitlementTree()` where obj is an object of the right type in order to call `createEntitlementTree()` in the `createUserGroupForm()` method.

Comment: Thank you jfriend. Changing it to this.createEntitlementTree() did the trick. Thanks a lot.